# Textbook for graduate number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am attending a graduate number theory, the professor did not assign any textbook. The materials are somewhere along the advanced/algebraic level such as Ring of Gaussian Integers, Quadratic Number Fields and especially about Euclidean Domain. Any suggestion to textbooks that I can read for self study? I prefer books that has lots of problems and their worked out solutions. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a good book is Problems in Algebraic Number Theory by Murty. It overs all of those things, and more and is 'problem-orientated,' so you do most of the work!

Comment: +1 the authors are Murty and Esmonde if I recall correctly

Comment: You do recall correctly!

Comment: Thank you for your pointer!

Answer (score 3):

Marcus, Number Fields, is another problem-oriented book.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your pointer!

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend some general graduate level texts,but it sounds from your question you're specifically looking for books with an algebraic bent.There aren't that many algebraic number theory texts-you'd think there would be, but it seems to be a fairly specialized-if important-area of mathematics. *Algebraic Number Theory* by Jürgen Neukirch is considered by most people I know to be the best of the modern algebraic number theory textbooks and it has a lot of exercises. There's also the classic book by Serge Lang of the same title,but it may be a bit out of date by now. Remember, to learn this subject you really need a very good grasp of basic algebra, particularly Galois theory, so it might be a good idea to consult a text on field theory. My favorite is Morandi's wonderful book.

Comment: Thank you! I will surely give them a look. For one thing I know Serge Lang is a very prolific writer, I saw many books authored by him.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus's book Number Fields is written in ideal language. It is very classical, and has many good problems (sometimes several problems in a row lead to a bigger conclusion). However, the more advanced language (and preferred by many current mathematicians) is through valuation-theory approach. For this direction, I would recommend Weiss's Algebraic Number Theory.